# How can I solve this basic probability question?

Tags: probability

I am playing a game,I have 10 boxes. Exactly one of the boxes contains a pill ,the game ends as soon as I guess the correct box(i,e. the box containing the pill).
Even if I make an incorrect guess, I get few more chances to make my guess and the most important thing to note is:-I don't remember the box I selected last time. :-)

After each incorrect guess, 10 more empty boxes get added to the whole set. :-( Thus, making the process more difficult. :((

Now, I have to calculate the probability of this game ending in 3rd move.

Also, I want to calculate the probability of this game ending in 4th move .

My work:- Probability of this game ending in 1 move:- 1/10(as I randomly select 1 box out of the ten boxes)

Probability of this game ending in 2nd move :- (9/10)*(1/20) .
Explanation, as the game ends in 2nd move, not the first move, there are 9/10 chances that we will reach the 2nd move(step).  And after reaching that move, we select 1 box from the 20 boxes(as 10 boxes are added after each incorrect guess,we have now, a total of 20 boxes) in front of us.

Please help!

Comment: Everything you've written sounds fine so far.  What exactly are you needing help with?  You seem to be well on your way to a correct answer on your own...

Comment: So, this is my answer :- for the 3rd move, as the game ends in 3rd-move, it does not end in second-move for sure, so the probability should be :- (9/10)*(19/20)*(1/30) . Am I correct?

Comment: Yes.$~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: Thanks  ! ! ! :-)

Comment: Can you help me out with out this very similar question,

Comment: Link:-https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101316/how-can-i-maximize-the-probability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the answer by your own method.
As you said,the possiblity that game end after n times,should be
$9/10*19/20*29/30*...*(10(n-1)-1)/(10(n-1))*1/10n$

Comment: Can you help me out with out this very similar question

Comment: Link:-https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101316/how-can-i-maximize-the-probability